# Simplifying an ugly function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coding-style, functional-programming

I have defined the function `f1`

```
f1 p = foldl (\x y -> x ++ y ++ "\t") "" (map (foldl (++) "") p)
```

that will take

```
[["4","0","1"],["5","2","3"]]
```

and yield

```
"401\t523\t"
```

but is a function as ugly as it can get. I am sure there is a simpler way to implement the same function. Can anybody give me some clue about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function composition is your friend.  So is intercalate, from Data.List

```
f1 = intercalate "\t" . map concat
```

Edit: whoops, misread your output.  You want "\t" at the end of all of them, not just between them.  In that case, it's closer to

```
f1 = concat . map ((++ "\t") . concat)
```

Comment: That doesn't include the `'\t'` at the end.

Comment: Good one. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use Data.List for this project :(

Comment: devoured elysium, well, my second function doesn't use anything from Data.List

Comment: `f1 = concatMap ((++"\t") . concat)` or `f1 xxs = do xs <- xxs; concat xs ++ "\t"` would also be good equivalents to your second version. That said, this was homework for someone from last semester so I doubt my response is timely. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As a suggestion for the *approach* to solving something similar to this in the future (supplimenting Carl's actual solution), what you could do is look at how a Haskell library solves the problem. For example, `Data.List.unwords` does something similar to what you want.

So, you might try looking into:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html

Finding `unwords` in this document, you'll notice there is a "source" link. Clicking there will bring you to the source of how the library implements it. Usually, the function isn't that large and may give you some ideas on how to generalize (or specialize) your function from the library.